# Tesseract has crashed

Tags: ios, crash, tesseract

[image]

I am using tesseract on my iOS device and it was working properly until recently it started to crash on me. I have been testing with the same image over and over again and prior to now I had it working about 75 times consecutively. The only thing I can think of is that I deleted the app from my iOS device and then ran it again through Xcode.

I am far from an expert on tesseract and I could really use some advice on what to do next, it would truly be a disappointment for all the hours I put in to go to waste because I cannot read the image anymore. Thank you

This is the crash error it appears to happen when the tesseract file in this method

```
- (BOOL)recognize 
{
    int returnCode = _tesseract->Recognize(NULL);// here is where the arrow points on the crash
    return (returnCode == 0) ? YES : NO;
}
```

This is an old question from Alex G and I don't see any answer.
Does anyone find the root cause and solution? Please advice. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using `AVCaptureSession` to take continuously photo and passing to tesseract after some image processing.

So before passing UIImage to tesseract for recognising you should check with this:

```
 CGSize size = [image size];//your image
 int width = size.width;
 int height = size.height;

 if (width < 100 || height < 50) {//UIImage must contain some some size
        //Consider as invalid image
          return;
   }

 //This condition is not mandatory.            
  uint32_t* _pixels = (uint32_t *) malloc(width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));
    if (!_pixels) {
          return;
         //Consider as invalid image

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try with your solution.